# Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://my.site.com".

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, recaptcha, google-developer-tools

I am using google reCaptcha v2.0 and this is working in the same domain when i am trying to do it with a sample html page but same thing is not working when I am trying to integrate with the full production page. After clicking on reCaptcha checkbox it's keep on loading for sometimes and after that it is throwing the error below in details.

`Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://my.site.com". The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.`

I have tried removing http, https and just kept // so that site protocol can match but no luck.
Would be a great help if anyone has a solution here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just open your site with `https://your-domain.com` and it will work

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach: But my site is not SSL enabled and I don't know what is the impact if will add a self certified SSL. Is there any thing else you can see here  ?

Answer (score 3):

When the src is running on https, your web server must be SSL enabled

Comment: This was absolutely my problem. Thanks so much for this, was driving me crazy why my cors wasn't taking!

Answer (score 1):

Change the recaptcha library URL from https to http

Chrome and other modern browsers will avoid mix HTTP with HTTPS.

Comment: I have tried that one but not working. Even same thing working on same domain with http while doing a sample html page with only captcha implemented. But the problem arrived when i tried integrating with whole page.

Comment: Same here, running on locahost. Removed https pu http. Same error. Even tried: //www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js. Still errors. Lame in so many ways.